# How to get values of same class/properties in Selenium C#?

Tags: c#, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am currently automating tests to compare expected and actual endorsements on a summary page.

How can I read all endorsements values on the page shown on the summary page.These can change, meaning there can be 2-5 depending on different input. I have tried Xpath and CSS selector but have had no luck. Here are the elements properties for two endorsements the rest of the endorsements will have same properties (elements wise) just different values.

I want to be able to get all the endorsements listed on the page so I can input to my excel sheet for comparison against expected endorsement.

ENDORSEMENT 1:

```
         <div class="guidance smaller ng-scope" ng-repeat="end in 
          prop.Endorsements">
          <a ng-href="#c03770af-3724-4c3a-a240-e341c0d2c3ef" ng-bind-
          html="end.Name" class="ng-binding" href="#c03770af-3724-4c3a-
          a240-e341c0d2c3ef">Restricted Theft</a>
          </div>
          <a ng-href="#c03770af-3724-4c3a-a240-e341c0d2c3ef" ng-bind-
          html="end.Name" class="ng-binding" href="#c03770af-3724-4c3a-a240-
          e341c0d2c3ef">Restricted Theft</a>
```

ENDORSEMENT 2:

```
       <div class="guidance smaller ng-scope" ng-repeat="end in 
       prop.Endorsements">
       <a ng-href="#93ff9067-f64c-4879-933d-8b0a1d077e74" ng-bind-
        html="end.Name" class="ng-binding" href="#93ff9067-f64c-4879-933d-
        8b0a1d077e74">Malicious Damage Exclusion</a>
        </div>
         <a ng-href="#93ff9067-f64c-4879-933d-8b0a1d077e74" ng-bind-
         html="end.Name" class="ng-binding" href="#93ff9067-f64c-4879-933d-
         8b0a1d077e74">Malicious Damage Exclusion</a>
```

Comment: Did you end up copying the `<a>` tags again in duplicate within the published _HTML_?

Comment: Nope just checked thats actually how it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a XPath expression to catch all the a elements at once and store them in a list.

When there are no other anchor tags then the Endorsements:

```
IList<IWebElement> listOfEndorsements= Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//a"));
```

When there are other kind of anchor tags you can try:

```
IList<IWebElement> listOfEndorsements= Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[contains(@ng-repeat,'prop.Endorsements')]/a"));
```

Then you can use a ForEach loop to extract from the list of IWebElements the information you need.Like:

```
foreach (var endorsement in listOfEndorsements)
{
    var text = endorsement.Text;
}
```

Comment: Ill try this now, my solution did not work you were correct!

Comment: I just edited the second XPath expression. A right parenthesis was missing

Comment: With the fooreach loop how do I make it so its all in one string like "Theft,Exclusion,Flood"? Thanks for the help

Comment: You can use StringBuilder to concatenate strings in a loop. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/concatenate-multiple-strings